# SvelteKit: Error: Not found: /tutorial/icons/md.svg

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I created a svelte app with

```
npm create svelte@latest (where I chose the demo app)
npm install
npm run dev
```

When I visit http://localhost:5173, the app seems to work but in the terminal I get the following error:

```
Error: Not found: /tutorial/icons/md.svg
    at resolve (C:/temp/SvelteRuleEditor1/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:483:13)
    at resolve (C:/temp/SvelteRuleEditor1/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:285:5)
    at #options.hooks.handle (C:/temp/SvelteRuleEditor1/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/index.js:56:56)
    at Module.respond (C:/temp/SvelteRuleEditor1/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:282:40)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you change anything or just run the base code?